# Rewrite Rule only applying to single link per page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all links within my site from the subdirectory /course/ to /courses/.

I used the code below in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^course/(.*)$ /courses/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This works on the first link it comes across on any page, but never on any subsequent links, which still go to the old /course/ subdirectory.

It doesn't matter which link, it's just whatever course is linked to first on whichever page, will work fine but subsequent ones will not.

Is there a simple reason for this and an easy fix?

Comment: It is normal that the links do not change in the page, they only change if you click on it. Some links may change, however, if they are relative (and not absolute).

Comment: I do mean when I click on them. The first link when clicked on does the redirect but any others do not.

Comment: Even if you do not always click the first one at the top of the page? It can not be a problem related to this .htaccess which is correct

Comment: Yes, even if I do not click the first one. Very strange if the code is correct.

Comment: Does the problem also present if you visit the URLs directly rather than by clicking through? Could you list a few example URLs?